# How do I Select all from one table where 2 columns in same table

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to query some data from my database and show data in my application. but I got an error on query. I'm don't know how to solve it. this my query code.

```
SELECT * FROM User_Table WHERE User_ID , Order_ID AND User_ID = 1234 , Order_ID = 1234";
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting a where condition like this? WHERE User_ID , Order_ID

Comment: Please show us your actual code.  Do you really want to search for the same ID for two logically different columns?

Comment: What database you are using, MySQL, SQL Server etc,.. Either way this doesn't look like valid syntax to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectify your **`SELECT`** statement.

```
"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +" WHERE User_ID='" + "1234" + "' AND Order_ID ='" + "1234" + "'";
```

Don't use **`HARD-CODED`**(static) Value.

Receive **`_userID,_orderID`** from Parameter.

```
"SELECT  * FROM " + User_Table  +" WHERE User_ID='"+ _userID +"' AND Order_ID ='" +_orderID+ "'";
```

Comment: why did you put User_ID twice in your where statement?

Comment: I think the OP should ideally be using a prepared statement here (not my downvote).

Comment: Why are you putting everything into concatenated strings? OP didn't do that why would you suggest that?

Comment: It isn't _wrong_, but in general prepared statements should be used, rather than hard-coding escaped portions of a query

Comment: If the account numbers in the query are truly hard-coded, and will never change based on input from the app, then I don't see anything wrong with what you wrote, and it can be accepted.  Otherwise, use prepared statements.